# Why does this strategy only take 2 trades a day?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

the strategy works fine i just need it to take more than 2 trades a day(without counting the one that closes all the trades at the end of the day can someone please help?

https://it.tradingview.com/v/wkwvEkmS/

ps the creator of the script doest respond in any form of social media

Comment: please a im desperate

Comment: Specify based on which condition you want to take the second trade. Since the logic for first trade is at a particular time, if condition is long buy it, if short then sell it. Do you want to execute the second trade at some other time, or based on some other logic.

Comment: i dont whant any specific time or trade i just want the strategy to function even after the 2 trades(1 short and 1 long) if the conditions are met

Answer (score 0):

This strategy, as coded, takes a single trade per day. To change the behaviour, you would need to change the code to allow more trades per day.

If you see the code, you can see that it only takes a trade when the code is at the specified start time and the condition is satisfied.

Removing the start time constraint or modifying it such that any trades can be taken *after* the start time will solve the issue.

Comment: i tred but still no use the strategy still takes 1 long and short per day if the conditions are met

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).